# Change color of input if its not empty (Angular)

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, ng-class

I've already seen some posts but nothing really helped me.
I have an input field and I want to change the color to red, if something is filled in.

I tried to check with ng-class if question.value is filled but I think I was doing it wrong.
I tried like this:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="question.value" ng-class="{red: question.value}">
</md-input-container>
```

I appreciate every help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Show what you tried using `ngClass`.

Comment: That's not how to use `ngClass`; the correct syntax should be `[ngClass]=""`

Comment: As @Edric said use `[ngClass]="'red': question.value"`;

Comment: More info: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code to this:

```
[ngClass]="'red': question.value";
```

Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QJLSXcpcELw3ZbMhlbyJ?p=preview)

Hope this helps.